# Saving nested json object path to a variable via recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

Is there a way to save the "path" of a json object to a variable?  That is, if I have something like this:

```
var obj = {"Mattress": {
                    "productDelivered": "Arranged by Retailer",
                    "productAge": {
                                "year": "0",
                                "month": "6"
                                }
                    }
       };
```

How can I loop through and save each key node name to a variable? eg. (I need it in this format): Mattress[productDelivered], Mattress[productAge][year], Mattress[productAge][month]

I have got partly there in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4cEwf/ but as you can see in the log, year and month don't get separated but append to the array as well.  I know this is because of the looping I have going on but I'm stuck on how to progress to get the data format I require. The flow I have set up in the fiddle is emulating what I need.

Is there a way I haven't considered to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var obj = {
    "Mattress": {
        "productDelivered": "Arranged by Retailer",
        "productAge": {
            "year": "0",
            "month": "6"
        }
    }
};

var array = [];

function process(obj, array, current){
    var ikey, value;
    for(key in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            value = obj[key];
            ikey = current ? current + '[' + key + ']' : key;
            if(typeof value == 'object'){
                process(value, array, ikey)
            } else {
                array.push(ikey)
            }
        }
    }
}
process(obj, array, '');
console.log(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2mbkQ/)

Comment: Wow!  That's exactly what I was after :D  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"Mattress": {
                    "productDelivered": "Arranged by Retailer",
                    "productAge": {
                                "year": "0",
                                "month": "6"
                                }
                    }
       };
var Mattress = new Array();
for(var i in obj.Mattress){
    if(typeof(obj.Mattress[i])==='object'){
        for(var j in obj.Mattress[i]){
            if(Mattress[i]!=undefined){
                Mattress[i][j] = obj.Mattress[i][j];
            }
            else{
                Mattress[i] = new Array();
                Mattress[i][j] = obj.Mattress[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        Mattress[i] = obj.Mattress[i];
    }
}     
for(var i in Mattress){
    if(typeof(Mattress[i])==='object'){
        for(var j in Mattress[i]){
            alert(j+":"+Mattress[i][j]);
        }
    }
    else{
        alert(i+":"+Mattress[i]);
    }
}
```